# Accessing Set-Cookie from Response Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, axios, setcookie

I've been trying to access the Set-Cookie value from the response headers. I have went through a lot of questions on here and also through other forums. The cookie is not 'HTTPOnly', SameSite: None, Secure: True.

I'm trying to make a post request, response status is 302(Redirect) and also the response body(in PostMan) is {redirect: '/next/', someId: 'random_id_value'}.
However no matter how much I try to access the set-cookie, I'm failing at it.

I have used the CORS extension as well. Changed 'withCredentials: true', "credentials: 'include'". Used a proxy too. Also, I'm using localhost:3000 to render the page in my react dev server.

Really hoping that someone could give me a solution to access the set-cookie.

Comment: document.cookie?

Comment: You must add SSL to your domain, then you can access cookies value otherwise not possible. But if you are running from your local machine or localhost or IP address then you are not facing this problem. I have already fetched this problem and already solved it.

If not posible add ssl at that time, then you can use localstorage.

Comment: @JaromandaX the cookie received in the response header is not set in the Application/Cookie. So, I can't really access it via document.cookie

Comment: @BulbulSarker I'm running this from my local machine through Localhost and I'm facing this problem. Is there any way to get the Set-Cookie value without making changes to the backend server? I'm receiving the data in response headers which is visible in Network but the cookie is not set in Application/Cookie or Application/Localstorage

Comment: Are cookies  set in the browser?

Comment: @BulbulSarker No. If they were, I would've tried accessing them using document.cookie

Comment: what you use in frontend? angular, vue or anything ......

Comment: If the cookie isn't available in document.cookie then it must be for a reason

Comment: @BulbulSarker at a guess its reactjs since that is a tag used for this question

Comment: Which npm package did you use for cookies?

Answer (score 2):

In accordance with the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org), client code cannot read `Set-Cookie` response headers, even if the server happens to be configured for CORS and lists `Set-Header` in its responses' `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header. See [this section of the standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name):

> A forbidden response-header name is a header name that is a byte-case-insensitive match for one of:
>
> - `Set-Cookie`
> - `Set-Cookie2`

and [further down](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name):

> A CORS-safelisted response-header name[...] is a header name that is a
> byte-case-insensitive match for one of
>
> - [...]
> - Any item in [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`] that is not a forbidden response-header name.